# Remove Duplicate words/strings from Oracle table using Regular Expressions

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I want to remove duplicate strings from the `Col B`. For example :"New Cap Grp" is repeated five times in second record.

```
Col A   Col B
-----   -----
WDSA    ALT COMPANY, III & New Group
1101    New Cap Grp & New Cap Grp & New Cap Grp & New Cap Grp & New Cap Grp 
2255    Tata Associates Inc. & Tata Associates Inc.& Towers Watson 
3355    Picard Lorens, Inc. & Tata Associates Inc. & Tata Associates Inc. 
8877    Morphy Companies, Inc. & Morphy Companies, Inc. & Tele Pvt.Ltd
```

I am new to regular expressions so I am not able to figure out how exactly this can be achieved. If anyone knows how to handle such scenarios then please help me.

Comment: This goes without saying that you know the duplicated value in each record right?

Comment: Yes, I know the dupilcate values in each record.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible do using only regexp expresion because you must do update for **Col B*** value.

It's easier do on ***PL/SQL***, I try do it:

### Create table for test data

```
create table test
    (
        id   number,
        text varchar2(100)
    );
```

### Insert test data

```
insert into test values (1, 'ALT COMPANY, III & New Group');
insert into test values (2, 'New Cap Grp & New Cap Grp & New Cap Grp & New Cap Grp & New Cap Grp');
insert into test values (3, 'Tata Associates Inc. & Tata Associates Inc.& Towers Watson');
insert into test values (4, 'Picard Lorens, Inc. & Tata Associates Inc. & Tata Associates Inc.');
insert into test values (5, 'Morphy Companies, Inc. & Morphy Companies, Inc. & Tele Pvt.Ltd');
```

### PL/SQL block:

```
declare
    l_new_column_value varchar2(1024) := '';
begin
    -- go on all row
    for x in (select id, text from test)
    loop
        -- work with each row, do from one row several by separation symbol '&' and take distinct value
        for concat_text in (
            select distinct trim(regexp_substr(text, '[^&]+', 1, level)) as part_value
            from
                (
                    select text
                    from test
                    where id = x.id
                )
            connect by instr(text, '&', 1, level - 1) > 0)
        loop
            -- formiration new uniq value 
            l_new_column_value := l_new_column_value || concat_text.part_value || ' & ';
        end loop;
        -- undate raw data
        update test
            set text = substr(l_new_column_value, 0, length(l_new_column_value)-3)
        where id = x.id;
        l_new_column_value := '';
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I was looking for a solution using only sql with regular expressions, but now it seems that it is not possible.